# Where am I? What happened? What should I do?

Tags: lateral-thinking

I'm having a total blackout.

I'm in this weird place. I don't really recognize it, but I feel like I might not recognize anything at this point. I barely know who I am...

So everyone here has a different color, and I can tell they are from many different countries. Doesn't look like it's an issue to anyone though, which I guess is a good thing.

I keep getting yelled at for some reason. Makes my head hurt. (Maybe it was hurting before? can't remember). Seems like I'm the only one getting yelled at mostly. Maybe it has something to do with those codes that others seem to use to communicate. I don't know what they mean.

Why doesn't anyone come to help me? I'm obviously showing distress!

I'm getting really anxious. There are two options in front of me. Which should I choose? left? right? both? neither?

I just want them to stop yelling...

---

**Edit:**
Rewrote in a friendlier format. Content didn't change but some information was added

Hints

1)

> Headache and blackout are related

2)

> Everyone seems to be in a rush, maybe that's why they don't stop to help me?

3)

> It's not their skin that has a different color

Comment: You are on Puzzling SE, and you should add some more clues to better distinguish the intended answer from the many plausible alternatives ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess that you are a

> car stalled at an intersection

So everyone here has a different color, and I can tell they are from many different countries. Doesn't look like it's an issue to anyone though, which I guess is a good thing.

> Cars are manufactured in different countries and come in a variety of colors

I keep getting yelled at for some reason. Makes my head hurt. (Maybe it was hurting before? can't remember). Seems like I'm the only one getting yelled at mostly.

> The other cars are honking at you because you aren't moving

Maybe it has something to do with those codes that others seem to use to communicate. I don't know what they mean.

> Traffic signs and signals are code for information about driving, cars also communicate with turn signals and breaklights

Why doesn't anyone come to help me? I'm obviously showing distress!

> It's dangerous to get out of the car in traffic

There are two options in front of me. Which should I choose? left? right? both? neither?

> You should choose the right option because that is the gas pedal and then you will move and everyone will stop yelling at you :)

Comment: The part about the distress is not accurate, but good job :)

Comment: Does the distress part have to do with ROT13(unmneq yvtugf)?

Comment: I think it's because of a ROT13(oernxqbja)

Comment: How do you show distress while in a car?

Answer (score 6):

You are

> Playing [Agar.io](http://agar.io)

Everyone here is treated the same because

> All of them start out teeny tiny no matter where you play.

It isn't tamed or tolerant because

> You need to eat other people to survive and dominate

There isn't much to say because

> You don't have an option of chatting or communicating with other people in the game. How much can a big blob say anyway?

You need codes to communicate

> Team players can signal at specific times to execute some moves.

No one approaches to seem I'm Ok

> They'll probably eat you if they can

What on earth did I say

> You can't say anything it's a game

There are two options before me

> Two small blobs. I say choose the one on the right.

What you should do?

> If you know tricksplitting I'll suggest that.

This obviously isn't the answer you might be looking for. But since it comes so close to your lines, I posted it anyway.

Answer (score 5):

I would say

> A baby in a maternity

Because:

total blackout:

> You have quite no memories

You don't know who you are:

> You still have no memory

People of different colors, without issues:

> The babies can have any color, but don't care

The head hurt:

> You're just born, so the head has been compressed during labour

Everyone yell:

> Babies yell all the time

You're anxious and nobody help you:

> You can't tell anything, and it is normal for you to cry

Answer (score 5):

You are a:

> NYSE Floor Trader

The different colors:

> Floor traders are required to wear different colored jackets to identify the firm they work for

The different nationalities:

> You'll find just about every nationality on the floor

You're being yelled at because:

> You're the market maker for a listing that's suddenly of great interest

The codes are:

> Stock symbols, prices, lot size

The two options in front of you are:

> Buy button on right, or sell button on left

You don't know what's happening because:

> You just lost $750 million of your firms capital on a short squeeze and are in a state of shock (seen it happen)

Comment: Good answer and welcome to Puzzling Stack Exchange! :) @WharfRat

Answer (score 3):

You are

> A boxer.

Regardless of color or country of birth 
every one here is treated the same 
you might think it's a tolerant place 
but in my experience it's not quite so tame

> On the ring, everybody obeys to the same rules, and of course it's not a place to discuss world peace.

You must know codes to communicate 
or there's not much you can say 
even when my distress is overt, 
no one approaches to see I'm OK 
in the rest of the time I keep getting yelled at
I don't know what on earth did I say?

> You communicate through gestures of the hands  (I think). When a boxer is at disadvantage, he just keeps on boxing. During a match, people around the ring and the boxers' trainers yell at them, either to incite them or to give them suggestions.

There are options before me 
two, let's consider 
should I pick the left, or the right 
maybe both? maybe neither?

> Before the boxer there are his two fists, left and right. He can decide which one to use, or even decide to just defend himself by raising them in front of him.

Comment: Which explains the headache and the blackout, of course.

Answer (score 1):

You are...

> *a recruit in the armed forces.*

1st paragraph

> All recruits are treated the same. The commanders aren't exactly tolerant of their mistakes...

2nd paragraph

> You are under stress from training, but are yelled at by your commanders to suck it up (which is what you should do!)

Comment: In the armed forces it makes quite a different what your country of birth is, they don't recruit people from other countries :)

Answer (score 0):

Your are a --

> A social media app, where everyone is judged equally bad, you need codes like emotes to communicate and choices between left right may be coming from Tinder :P

Answer (score 0):

I would say

> Microphone head

So it's yelled at, and the head hurts.

Left/Right can refer to

> balance

And the codes used for communication

> are sounds, but "codes" or signals to the microphone itself.

Not sure about the colors/countries.

Answer (score 0):

My guess: you are

> a newbie in an MMORPG

So everyone here has a different color, and I can tell they are from many different countries. Doesn't look like it's an issue to anyone though, which I guess is a good thing.

> User characters/sprites are customized by users to be all sort of different colors, and users tend to be international in nature

Keep getting yelled at

> chats within the app, and users can be cruel to and angry with new users who haven't figured out the ropes of the MMORPG yet

Answer (score 0):

You are...

> Having a "near death experience". The strange place and people from all nationalities are some kind of imagined afterlife?

The people yelling and talking in codes...

> You are really in a hospital, medical staff are trying to save your life after some kind of accident, which also explains the headache, blackout, disorientation.

The two options before you...

> ..are live or die.